# Changing CornerRadius of list items in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: Example of the borders]

Here I'm showing an example of both borders that I am able to put around the list items. The outer border is defined with:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
             <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                       <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                       <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                       <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
```

This border would be ideal, as it goes around the entire list item, but I do not have access to `CornerRadius` with this border.

The second border is defined as:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     DataTemplate>
         <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="4" >
```

I would be ok with using either border, except with option 1 I cannot control the corner radius, and with option 2, there is a bunch of white space left in the list items (basically the space you see between border 1 and border 2).

So I would like to either change the `CornerRadius` of border 1, or extend border 2 out to where border 1 is sitting.

Edit:

The style needed to be declared as:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Resources>
                      <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                 </Style.Resources>
                 <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                 <Setter Property="Height" Value="150" />
                 <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
            </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: 1) Set the ListBoxItem's Template property via a Setter. Give it a ControlTemplate that does only what you want. 2) In the ItemContainerStyle, set Padding, Margin, and BorderThickness to zero. Use only the Border in your ItemTemplate. Give that Border whatever Margin you like, if any.

Comment: That is the problem, `CornerRadius` is not available as a property inside `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">`

Comment: @ChrisW. I had actually looked at that before posting, it wasn't working for me, but I realize what I had done wrong. I hadn't embedded the `Style.Resources` properly. Thanks for the comments